# How long does smite evil last?

Tags: pathfinder-1e

[Smite evil](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/paladin#TOC-Smite-Evil-Su-) is:

> Once per day, a paladin can call out to the powers of good to aid her
>   in her struggle against evil. As a swift action, the paladin chooses
>   one target within sight to smite. If this target is evil, the paladin
>   adds her Cha bonus (if any) to her attack rolls and adds her paladin
>   level to all damage rolls made against the target of her smite. If the
>   target of smite evil is an outsider with the evil subtype, an
>   evil-aligned dragon, or an undead creature, the bonus to damage on the
>   first successful attack increases to 2 points of damage per level the
>   paladin possesses. Regardless of the target, smite evil attacks
>   automatically bypass any DR the creature might possess.

There is no duration, and the wording is a little messy.

How long does each effect last?
How many targets are affected for which effect* by which attack (Say a Paladin has multiple attacks for a round)

- A/E win!

Comment: -1 for lack of research effort: all you had to do was read the whole description of the ability, not stop at the first paragraph.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the description of smite evil:

> The smite evil effect remains until the target of the smite is dead or
>   the next time the paladin rests and regains her uses of this ability.

Also, the section you quote says:

> As a swift action, the paladin chooses one target within sight to smite.

All of the effects of smite evil stay in effect until the target dies or the paladin rests.  One target is affected at a time.

Basically, smite evil isn't an attack at all; it's a debuff.  The paladin chooses a target, and gains a bunch of bonuses against that target until the target dies.  In other editions, smite evil was a separate attack, but it doesn't work that way in Pathfinder.